# CSS/images multiple borders / edges must repeat whenever the content gets bigger

Tags: css

I want to make something like this

[image]

Can you see how the edges have 3 borders? with a style, how do I make something exactly like this?

I got a plan,

Crop the head of the content,

crop the content area,

and crop the footer of the content

So the middle part will repeat with the content, but im not to sure how to make this.

any ideas?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? You may have an idea, but did you try to put it into action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with divs, borders and absolute positioning.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wwA3q/2/)

Just absolutely position the divs and change the top/left slightly

```
div {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
}
#first{
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px; 
}
#second{
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. I have tried this, but something doesn't work when i converted the div { into a class.

http://generationx-pk.net/tools/index.html

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/wwA3q/9/